# Most efficient way to determine if an integer is odd or even using modern C++ techniques

Tags: c++, performance, c++17, constexpr

I wrote this simple helper `constexpr` function:

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr bool isEven(uint32_t value) { return ((value%2) == 0); }
```

It is pretty straight forward. I was wondering if this would be considered the most efficient way to determine if some integer value is odd or even? I'm not worried about templating this function for different integral types at the moment. I'm just looking for efficiency and performance while keeping portability in mind.

**Edit**

To give some context, I might be calling this function within a loop that could iterate 100,000 times to 100,000,000 times or more... So efficiency is key here, but portability is still a factor...

I had thought about "bitwise operations" by checking the least most significant bit as others had stated in their comments or answers, however, I wasn't sure if the compilers would optimize the modulo operator in this context.

Concerning portability, I wasn't sure if "endian" or "integral conventions" would be a leading factor towards which implementation should be used. Considering a system that implements only 1's complement instead of 2's complement, or one that uses Big Endian instead of Little may need to be taken into account.

Comment: How about testing the *least significant bit* of `value` with the bitwise and operator (`&`) ?

Comment: @眠りネロク I was thinking about that too... I could be calling this function within a loop that will iterate 100,000 - 10,000,000 times...

Comment: @FrancisCugler: "*I might be calling this function within a loop that could iterate 100,000 times to 100,000,000 times or more*" Then your efficiency concerns should primarily be about how to deliver that much data to the CPU as fast as possible, *not* the performance of doing a test on an integer. This is the problem with premature optimization; you're so focused on what you think might be the problem that you ignore the real performance issue: memory bandwidth and caching.

Comment: Some thoughts, if you don't mind. Do you really need this check to generate a list of N primes? Do you really need to take one's complement implementations into account? Note that you didn't, `uint32_t` is two's complement by definition and, well, unsigned. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/WiFxZA), only icc generates "odd" code.

Comment: @Bob__ As the code currently stands for using `uint32_t`, no you are correct,  but if I decide to template this function for any integral type... it could then be a concern. As for the list of primes, I can call this function and if it returns back that's even I can skip that value in the generation of the prime numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly use the `&` ( *AND* ) operator.

If `x` is your `int`:

```
x & 1  // returns 1 if odd, else 0
```

This is probably the best way to find if an integer is odd or even.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if bit twiddling would be more efficient than the modulo operator, or if the compilers would optimize it or not...

Comment: @FrancisCugler You can be assured that & is the least cost and most efficient operation you can get to find the parity of an integer (odd or even)

Comment: @FrancisCugler Yeah, possibly they will get optimized to the same instructions, but just to be sure, you can't beat this.

Comment: To add, x & 1 will give wrong answers on one's complement systems. You are better off with modulo( % operator ) if portability is a requirement for you, as the efficiency or optimization gained by using & operator is just marginal anyways.

Comment: @Abhishek that's the clarity I was after, thank you. Efficiency is of high importance but also being portable is a concern!

Comment: @Abhishek If I truly wanted to be that verbose about it. I could turn this into a templated function, check to see which convention that system is using then make the decision of which implementation to use...

Comment: @FrancisCugler Well, if you wish you could probably do that, but then again the difference would be very marginal unless all you are planning to do is hell of a lot of even-odd check operation.

Comment: @Abhishek I'm planning on using this helper function in a templated function to generate a list of N prime numbers. So, it could be used quite heavily, depending on the size of the list to be generated! If it's only 100,000 entries, then it shouldn't be that big of an issue, but if the list to be generated has 100,000,000 or more entries, then I need it to be O(n) with very fast instructions.